# Gurobi Irreducible Subset ISS contains no conflict?

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi

I am using Gurobi's C++ interface to solve a mixed-integer programming problem. This model appeared to work perfectly, but when comparing the results to a local search heuristic, I found that a simple greedy local search produced better (and feasible) solutions. To see what was causing the problem I added some additional constraints for a small instance, enforcing the solution to be identical to the solution found by the local search procedure.

As expected, this resulted in an infeasible problem from which I had Gurobi determine the irreducible subset (ISS). However, when manually checking the ISS that was produced **I could find no conflict in the equations**.

The problem is a simple multi-mode scheduling problem where `x[i][m]` is a binary variable that represents the choice for mode `m` for activity `i`. Hence, a solution is constructed by selecting a single mode for each activity (=1 indicates that a mode has been selected, as enforced by constraint `c1`). The `DEBUG` constraints should enforce a specific decision to be made regarding the activity modes for all activities.

Constraint type `c2` simply calculates finishing times of activities based on their precedence relations, assigning values to the otherwise unconstrained finishing time variable `f[i]` for each activity. The finishing time of the final activity is then used in the `c_linduration` constraint to calculate (a part of) the objective function value represented by the variable `I^D`. Again, the `I^D` variable is not constrained by any other equation (if it was, the constraint should of course also be present in the ISS).

```
Maximize

Subject To
 c1[1]: x[1][0] + x[1][1] + x[1][2] + x[1][3] = 1
 c1[2]: x[2][0] + x[2][1] + x[2][2] + x[2][3] = 1
 c1[5]: x[5][0] + x[5][1] + x[5][2] + x[5][3] + x[5][4] + x[5][5] + x[5][6]
   + x[5][7] = 1
 DEBUG[1]: x[1][1] = 1
 DEBUG[2]: x[2][0] = 1
 DEBUG[5]: x[5][2] = 1
 c2[1][0]: - 7.709549903869629 x[1][0] - 11.21389961242676 x[1][1]
   - 11.91479969024658 x[1][2] - 8.410420417785645 x[1][3] - f[0] + f[1]
   >= 0
 c2[2][0]: - 11.00800037384033 x[2][0] - 7.770349979400635 x[2][1]
   - 7.122819900512695 x[2][2] - 7.122819900512695 x[2][3] - f[1] + f[2]
   >= 0
 c2[5][0]: - 2.499399900436401 x[5][0] - 2.883919954299927 x[5][1]
   - 3.84522008895874 x[5][2] - 3.268440008163452 x[5][3]
   - 3.076179981231689 x[5][4] - 3.460700035095215 x[5][5]
   - 2.307130098342896 x[5][6] - 2.499399900436401 x[5][7] - f[2] + f[5]
   >= 0
 c2[7][1]: - f[5] + f[7] >= 0
 c3: f[0] = 0
 c_linduration: 0.2000000029802322 f[7] + I^D[0] = 4.390739887814817
Bounds
 x[1][0] free
 x[1][1] free
 x[2][0] free
 x[2][1] free
 -infinity <= x[2][2] <= 1
 -infinity <= x[2][3] <= 1
 x[5][2] free
 x[5][6] free
 f[0] free
 f[1] free
 f[2] free
 f[5] free
 f[7] free
Generals
 x[1][0] x[1][1] x[1][2] x[1][3] x[2][0] x[2][1] x[2][2] x[2][3] x[5][0]
 x[5][1] x[5][2] x[5][3] x[5][4] x[5][5] x[5][6] x[5][7]
End
```

I have also tried lowering the integer precision from `1e-9` to `1e-6` because I thought this might be a rounding issue, but this had no effect. Removing the `c1` or `c3` constraint type also produces no change in the ISS that is produced. I am creating the ISS using the following statements:

```
//Optimize the model
model.optimize();

//calculate the ISS in case the model is infeasibel
model.computeIIS();
model.write("model.ilp");
```

Is there a Gurobi setting I might have missed or something else I might try? Or could there be an issue with the way in which I am constructing this ISS? I've been thinking about this for quite a while now and I really don't have a clue how to solve this... If it matters, I am working with Gurobi 6.0 and the LLVM C++ compiler on OS X.

All help is immensely appreciated!

L

Comment: Use of the C++ tag here doesn't seem appropriate as this isn't a question about C++.

Comment: I have removed the tag, I had added it because I use the C++ interface but you are right it has nothing to do with C++. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been identified by Kostja Siefen on the Gurobi google group forum: the issue was that I incorrectly assumed that the default lower bound for the `I^D` variable was -infinity, whereas the default lower bounds for Gurobi are actually 0. Hence, the problem was resolved by setting the lower bound equal to `-GRB_INFINITY`.

Comment: This is the standard convention for linear programming: that variables have a lower bound of zero.

Comment: ...if not specified.